# SML how to explicitly set a function parameter type to IntInf

Tags: sorting, sml, largenumber, selection-sort

I am trying to make a sorting function for unique large numbers in SML but the compiler keeps setting my function type to int instead of 'a. How can I explicitly tell the compiler to use IntInf?

Here is my code:

```
fun selectsort([a]) = [a]
  | selectsort(h::t) =
  if (hd(selectsort(t))) < h then hd(selectsort(t))::h::tl(selectsort(t))
  else h::selectsort(t);
```

when I try

```
fun selectsort([a]) = [a]
  | selectsort(l : IntInf list) =
  if (hd(selectsort(tl(l)))) < hd(l) then hd(selectsort(tl(l)))::h::tl(selectsort(tl(l)))
  else hd(l)::selectsort(tl(l));
```

it keeps giving me "Error: unbound type constructor: IntInf"

Comment: Solved using a workaround: `if (hd(selectsort(t)) + IntInf.fromInt(0)) < h + IntInf.fromInt(0) then hd(selectsort(t))::h::tl(selectsort(t))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntInf` is the name of a module, the type is named `IntInf.int`. Alas, your code somewhat simplified:

```
fun selectsort([a]) = [a]
  | selectsort(x::y::t : IntInf.int list) =
    if y < x then y::x::selectsort(t) else x::selectsort(y::t)
```

Note however that `IntInf` is an optional module that is not available on all implementations. (Also, you should add a case for the empty list.)

Comment: I made this for a very specific piece of code, so empty lists won't be sorted.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho, it's considered good style to add missing cases anyway and make them e.g. raise a `Domain` exception.